# Why do string additions give different answers?

Tags: java, string, associativity

```
System.out.println(7 + 5 + " ");
```

This prints out `12`, but in another order

```
System.out.println(" " + 5 + 7);
```

it prints out `57`.  Why is this?

Comment: Because L-to-R auto-conversions. One starts off as math then gets forced to a string, the other starts off as a string and stays that way (e.g., concatenation).

Comment: `"" + 5 => "5"`     then         `"5" + 7 => "57"`

Comment: i see it! but, why it happens?

Comment: @IGRZXC The relevant document is linked in Jon's answer: [JLS 15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)

Comment: I  saw ana read, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with `System.out.println`. You'll see exactly the same effect if you use:

```
String x = 7 + 5 + "";
String y = " " + 5 + 7;
```

It's got everything to do with *associativity*. The `+` operator is left-associative, so the above two statements are equivalent to:

```
String x = (7 + 5) + "";
String y = (" " + 5) + 7;
```

Now look at the results of the first expression in each case: `7 + 5` is just 12, as `int`... whereas `" " + 5` is "5" (a string).

Or to break it down further:

```
int x1 = 7 + 5;      // 12   (integer addition)
String x = x1 + "";  // "12" (conversion to string, then string concatenation)

String y1 = " " + 5; // "5"  (conversion to string, then string concatenation)
String y = y1 + 7;   // "57" (conversion to string, then string concatenation)
```

Justification: [JLS 15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) (additive operators):

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

Answer (score 0):

Easy. System.out.println(7 + 5 + " ") is viewed as a mathematical equation, whereas System.out.println(" " + 5 + 7) whereas having the space beforehand, Java (I'm assuming) views it as a string. Thus 'concatenating' the two.